# How can I get a relative path in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to create a program and compile it to WASM. The program runs on Windows and Unix.

The program generates a relative path for a `filename` from the given `base_path` and converts it to posix:

```rust
use pathdiff::diff_paths;

let relative_filename = diff_paths(filename, base_path).unwrap();
let path_parts = relative_filename.components().map(|component| component.as_os_str().to_str().unwrap()).collect::<Vec<&str>>();
let relative_posix_path = path_parts.join("/");
```

I thought this would allow me to generate a consistent relative path for both systems for example:

```rust
/// e.g. "/foo/", "/bar/baz.txt" -> "../bar/baz.txt"
/// e.g. "C:\foo\", "C:\foo\baz.txt" -> "../bar/baz.txt"
```

Unfortunately when compiled to WASM it seems not to be able to parse Windows file paths anymore.

Is there a cross platform way to handle paths in rust?

Comment: Currently, when targetting wasm, [stdlib uses the unix path implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/6609c6734de4df43e24d7672f8ae8786ecc8047e/library/std/src/sys/wasm/mod.rs#L35-L36).  It's not clear to me whether this is specified by wasm, or is a compile-time decision that has (perhaps erroneously?) been taken simply because the host environment is not then known.  In any event, for now it seems your only option is to translate to/from unix paths at runtime.  See also https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/66621